# How to limit the result of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I wrote an elasticsearch query to get only top 10 result in descending order

```
{

  "aggs": {
    "group_by_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.raw",
         "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting below error
I am getting the following error

```
Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10250]
```

How to rephrase my query to get the exact result of what I am looking for it. I dont know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that your complete query?

Comment: I hope so. I am not sure whether I need to add more filters or terms in it

Answer (score 2):

Not this `size` is the one to look for, but the one at the root of the query:

```
{
  "size": 10250,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.raw",
         "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error message is about that one. Check your query and, potentially, any query parameters under the form `?size=10250...`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a field called size in your document ? Because if not that's not how you use from/size. If there is indeed a field named size mapped as a number, I don't see any reason this query shouldn't work, it should still give 10 results by default.

Anyways the correct way of using from/size is

```
{
  "from": 0, "size": 10,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.raw",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you 10 results, ie. results from 0 with a size of 10

Comment: I have applied your concept but I am getting the below error. `nested: QueryPhaseExecutionException[Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10250]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level parameter.]; }`

Comment: There is no field like `size` in my document. i thought it was a builtin field.

Comment: My requirement is eventhough if I have 10000k events I need only top 10 events among all the events in my index.

Comment: I have no idea where it's getting the size "10250" from. Could you post your exact query and some details about the index and what you are trying to search exactly ? Anyways, I suggest you forget about the size of the result set for now and focus on getting your query correct, because like I said no matter how many hits are there for your query, elasticsearch will only show the first 10 results by default.

Comment: I am trying to execute your query using `ElasticTab` plugin.